# Isolate differing rows between two 2d arrays with different identifying keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-difference

Array one:

```
$arr1 = array(
    array("uid" => "cgajate"),
    array("uid" => "frankfurt9"),
    array("uid" => "ricoetc")
);
```

Array two:

```
$arr2 = array(
    array("uxid" => "cgajate"),
    array("uxid" => "ricoetc"),
    array("uxid" => "ricoetc1"),
    array("uxid" => "frankfurt9"),
    array("uxid" => "panterafan")
);
```

I have two multidimensional array (that as you can see above, do not share the same key name for the id, uxid vs uid). I am trying to find unmatched array on basis of comparing 'uid' and 'uxid' values and my expected result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uxid] => ricoetc1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [uxid] => panterafan
        )
)
```

Below is my code,I am trying to find matched value and remove from result array but when I am printing give me empty array.

```
  $tmpArray = array();
   foreach($arr1 as $data1) {
    $duplicate = false;
     foreach($arr2 as $data2) {
        if($data1['uid'] === $data2['uxid']) $duplicate = true;
      }
     if($duplicate === false) $tmpArray[] = $data1;
   }
   echo "<pre>", print_r($tmpArray);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)

Comment: Do you also want to find unmatched `uid` values? Or won't they exist?

Comment: I would have voted to close this as a duplicate except you have a different key for the arrays you want to compare, so it's not obvious to use `array_diff` for the solution.  May I suggest that you edit your question to stress the fact that the keys are different)?  Also, @mickmackusa's answer seems the most accurate because he takes the approach of first transforming the problem into one that can be solved easily by the core `array_diff` function.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 $arr1 = array(
        array("uid" => "cgajate"),
        array("uid" => "frankfurt9"),
        array("uid" => "ricoetc")
        );

         $arr2 = array(
        array("uxid" => "cgajate"),
        array("uxid" => "ricoetc"),
        array("uxid" => "ricoetc1"),
        array("uxid" => "frankfurt9"),
        array("uxid" => "panterafan")
        );

foreach($arr2 as $k => $v){

if (!in_array($v['uxid'], array_column($arr1, 'uid'))){

    $new[] =$v;     
}

}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: you should be checking witch array is bigger, because if you switch places of $arr1 and $arr2 you will get no result...if i am reading the code right

Comment: This approach is not optimized because it makes iterated calls of `array_column()` and each call of `in_array()` will be doing full scans of the first array.

Answer (score 1):

Most elegantly, inverse the functional effect of [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73552928/2943403).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ddHGF))

```
var_export(
    array_udiff(
        $arr2,
        $arr1,
        fn($a, $b) => ($a['uid'] ?? $a['uxid']) <=> ($b['uid'] ?? $b['uxid'])
    )
);
```

Since the `$a` and `$b` variables may relate to either/any of the input arrays, you must try to access one of the array's keys, then fallback to the other array's keys.

Output:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'uxid' => 'ricoetc1',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'uxid' => 'panterafan',
  ),
)
```

To re-index the output, just call `array_values()` on `array_udiff()`'s output ... if truly needed.